# vim case insensitive search with sensitive replace

Tags: vim

I have a file with this in it:

```
test
Test
```

Currently, if If I want to replace all cases of 'test' with 'foo', and 'Test' with 'Foo', I have to use two commands:

```
:%s/test/foo/g
:%s/Test/Foo/g
```

Is there any way that I can accomplish this with a single command?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is quite what you need: `:%s/test/foo/g | %s/Test/Foo/g`

Comment: Yes that works, but doesn't really help me out as I am trying to speed up the process.

Comment: Haha. Yeah... :) That is what I generally do, but I didn't feel 100% about providing it as an answer because, it being Vim, there's probably some other solution which will be super concise and awesome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this [vim plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) by tim pope will solve your problem, install it and
`%Subvert/{t}est/{f}oo/g` or `%Subvert/test/foo/g` (thanks for the comment) will do the trick

Comment: The plugin works, although you only need to type %Subvert/test/foo/g

Answer (score 13):

As my granpappy used to say, for every plugin there's a vim one-liner that's just as good.  Try

```
%s/\(test\|Test\)/\=submatch(0) =~ '^\l.*' ? 'foo' : 'Foo'/g
```

Explanation:

`%s/` substitute over the whole buffer

`\(test\|Test\)/` match for 'test' OR 'Test'

`\=` Make the substitute string use whatever the following expression evaluates to

`submatch(0)` In this context evaluates to the entire matched expression

`=~ '\l.*'` String-comparison for regex match (against a word starting with a lowercase letter)

`... ? 'foo' : 'Foo'` if-then-else expression which evaluates to 'foo' if ... is true, 'Foo' otherwise

`/g` Do this over the entire line

With slight modifications this should be more than enough to satisfy our needs.  References:

```
:help :s
:help :sub-replace-\=
:help expression
```

...I just want to put a little warning for anyone who tries to get into vim evaluations and expressions...  They are very counter-intuitive (I come from a C++ background, maybe if you come from bash or python it's less of an issue).  I found the following vimscript guide/ self-teaching lessons to be extremely helpful: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/

Comment: This is very cool but for some reason I can only get it to work if I use \u instead of \l (and then swap the two sides of the colon). When I use \l, it only uses the lowercase substitution.

Comment: @NeRoboto weird.  What version of vim?

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled May 13 2023 12:55:09)
macOS version - arm64

Comment: @NeRoboto Thanks for the catch - it was most likely my error (I tried on versions 7.4, 8.0, and 9.whatever).  I'm pretty sure that I tested it using the strings `test` and `TEST`, then changed it here to better match the question and did not retest.  Your workaround will work as long as there are no capital letters in the "lowercase option."  Otherwise, for the matching I guess it's correct to indicate "starting with lowercase" as `^\l` (or `^\u` for uppercase).  I've updated my answer.